# Is there a daily limit for absorption of vitamin B12?

Tags: veganism, b12, vitamins-and-minerals

I am interested in knowing whether there is some **biologically imposed limit for an amount of B12 that human body can absorb per day**. If so, what happens with the rest of the consumed B12? Is it just expelled from the body with other *waste*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if anyone knows of a concrete upper limit on how much can be absorbed. I think the more important point (as discussed in [your other question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/542/when-taking-b12-supplements-is-it-a-viable-strategy-to-take-higher-dose-every-f/544)) is that even at low to moderate doses the body doesn't absorb most of the B12 ingested in a supplement. Whatever upper limit there is, to reach it you would probably have to ingest much more than is required to ensure healthy levels of B12 in the body.

B12 is a water soluble vitamin, so whatever the body fails to absorb is excreted in urine.